# Can I add Formula to an cell from VBA without dollar symbol?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

For exmaple, I want add formula to all selected cell where I click.
The Cells.Address is good for recognise the cell, but when I add the formula, and I after see the cell, the vba add lock dollars symbol and I want avoid that.

e.g.: 
`r = Target.Row
Cells(r, 1).Formula = "=" & Cells(r, 2).Address & "*" & Cells(r, 3).Address`

Result in cell (if the target A1): `=$A$2 * $A$3`

But I want that result: `=A2 * A3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the first two criteria of the [`.Address`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) to `0`:

```
Cells(r, 1).Formula = "=" & Cells(r, 2).Address(0,0) & "*" & Cells(r, 3).Address(0,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set both the row-absolute and the column-absolute to false.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx shows in more detail.